# discord.py PILLOW image manipulation file not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@commands.command(name="wanted", aliases=["procurado"], description="Faz com que um usuário mencionado seja colocado em um cartaz de procurado")
    @commands.cooldown(1, 2, commands.BucketType.member)
    async def wanted(self, ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
      if member is None:
          member = ctx.author
      wanted = Image.open("wanted.png")
      asset = ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
      data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
      pfp = Image.open(data)
      pfp = pfp.resize((144,144)) 
      wanted.paste(pfp, (48,106))
      wanted.save("wanteddata.jpg")
      await ctx.send(file = discord.File("wanteddata.jpg"))
```

wanted.png are in the same folder of the code, when i use the command in console get this error

```
Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wanted.png'
```

Comment: Are you running the script from the same directory that it is in?

Comment: this code is Cogs/fun.py and wanted.png is Cogs/wanted.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your comment your project looks like this:

```
YourProject
├─ main.py
└─ Cogs
    ├─ fun.py
    └─ wanted.png
```

If you are running your bot from the `YourProject` directory like so:

```
\Some\directories\YourProject> python main.py
```

The script is trying to access `YourProject/wanted.png` not `YourProject/Cogs/wanted.png`.
You can fix it in 3 ways:

1. By providing full directory:

```py
Image.open("/Some/directories/YourProject/Cogs/wanted.png")
```

2. By specifing folder name (It will only work if you run your script from `YourProject` directory):

```py
Image.open("Cogs/wanted.py")
```

3. By making image relative to your `fun.py` file:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
Image.open(f"{filepath}/wanted.png")
```

I recommend using the 3rd option because then you can run your python file from wherever you want.

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped you, you should mark this as an answer for others to see that this problem is solved. :)